# Naming convention in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm trying to fix my code and have an issue about naming conventions. I think it should be *clinicId*, not *clinic_id*, but I'm not pretty sure about it. What's wrong with it?

```
public ArrayList<User> getClinicDoctorList(int clinic_id) throws SQLException{
```

Comment: [This is the document you're looking for](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) - so, yes, use `clinicId`.

Comment: 2021??? There ***must*** be a canonical question. What is it?

Comment: Some candidates: *[Using underscores in Java variables and method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150192/)* (2008), *[Use of underscore in variable and method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785175/)* (2013), *[Why do we add an _ (underscore) before a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677249/)* (2013), and *[Variable naming conventions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/)* (2009).

Comment: Please don't answer the same beginner questions over and over and over again. Please find the duplicate, indicate it in comments (or vote to close), and find some more interesting question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Java naming conventions recommend using camel case for method, class, and variable names.  So the suggestion would be to use this signature:

```java
public ArrayList getClinicDoctorList(int clinicId) throws SQLException;
```

That being said, using `clinic_id` is in fact legal Java, and the code would compile and run.  There are occasions where using underscore in names is required, such as interfacing with a framework which expects this naming convention.  One example would be a Java POJO which you intend to serialize out to JSON.  In this case, if you wanted JSON keys to be separated by underscore, rather than using camel base, you might also use underscores in the POJO.  But in general, the universal convention is to use camel case.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use clinic_id, but it not recommended. It is better to use **clinicId**

Some of the variable naming conversions are:

- It should start with a lowercase letter, such as id, name.
- It should not start with the special characters, like & (ampersand), $ (dollar), and _ (underscore).
- If the name contains multiple words, start it with the lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter, such as *firstName* and *lastName*.
- Avoid using one-character variables, such as *x*, *y*, and *z*

Answer (score -1):

For your reference, Here is a detailed view of naming conventions in java.

[image]

Since we are referring to a varible of integer type, we can use "clinic_id" or "clinicId" or any other name of your choice, unless naming conventions are not violated.
Although, it is always recommended to use Camel Case for naming variables in java ,because:

- Easy to read
- Easy to type
- Easy to understand

On the other hand, the use of underscores within the name can be found while naming ANSI constants in java, like:

"int MIN_WIDTH=4;"
"Int MAX_WIDTH=999;"

Comment: Using an image for this is bad for accessibility